# How to link 2 columns from a SQL database into an array en then looped through dynamically made controls

Tags: c#, sql, database, multidimensional-array

I am making a website for a restaurant and I'm using ASP C#.

What I intend to do is get 2 columns from a SQl database (a string and an integer) put them into an array an them those 2 through my dynamically made controls.

I will show you the code below.

```
        int aantal = getNumberOfRows();
        int loop = 0;


        conn = new SqlConnection(conString);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MenuVulling",conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        object[,] piclist = new object[aantal, 2];

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            // Create a new DataTable

            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow drRow in dt.Rows)
            {


                piclist[loop, 0] = (drRow["PictureLocation"].ToString());
                piclist[loop, 1] = (drRow["MenuId"].ToString());
                loop++;

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {

            conn.Close();
        }

        return piclist;
```

This is the method i made to get those 2 values from the database.

```
     public int dynamicControls(int aantal)
    {

        int loop = 0;
        Array url = getImageUrl();



        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= aantal; i++)
            {
                Table tafel = new Table();
                Panel panel = new Panel();
                Panel2.Controls.Add(panel);


                panel.Controls.Add(tafel);

                // nieuwe rij
                TableRow tRow1 = new TableRow();

                //rij in tafel zetten
                tafel.Controls.Add(tRow1);

                //image button
                TableCell tCellImg = new TableCell();
                tRow1.Controls.Add(tCellImg);
                ImageButton imgB1 = new ImageButton();
                tCellImg.Controls.Add(imgB1);
                imgB1.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imgB1_click);



                foreach (string s in url)
                {
                    // imgB1.ImageUrl = s;


                }
                imgB1.ID = "img " + i.ToString();

                //This is where i try to loop the item through the imagebuttons                          buttons to show the pictures in them.^^

                // upload controle
                TableCell tCellUpload = new TableCell();
                tRow1.Controls.Add(tCellUpload);
                FileUpload fileUp = new FileUpload();
                tCellUpload.Controls.Add(fileUp);
                fileUp.ForeColor = Color.RosyBrown;

                //2de row
                TableRow tRow2 = new TableRow();
                tafel.Controls.Add(tRow2);

                //cell voor de namen van de gerechten
                TableCell cellLblnmGerecht = new TableCell();
                cellLblnmGerecht.ID = "cellNmGerecht" + i.ToString();
                tRow2.Controls.Add(cellLblnmGerecht);

                //Label naam voor gerechten
                Label naamGerecht = new Label();
                naamGerecht.Text = "variabelnaam voor gerechten";
                naamGerecht.ID = i.ToString();
                cellLblnmGerecht.Controls.Add(naamGerecht);
                cellLblnmGerecht.ForeColor = Color.RosyBrown;

                //Nieuwe rij
                TableRow tRow3 = new TableRow();
                tafel.Controls.Add(tRow3);

                //Cell voor prijsLabel
                TableCell cellPrijs = new TableCell();
                tRow3.Controls.Add(cellPrijs);

                //Label controle
                Label lblPrijs = new Label();
                lblPrijs.Text = "Prijs: ";
                cellPrijs.Controls.Add(lblPrijs);
                lblPrijs.ForeColor = Color.RosyBrown;

                //cell voor textbox
                TableCell celltxtPrijs = new TableCell();
                celltxtPrijs.ID = "cellPrijs" + i.ToString();
                tRow3.Controls.Add(celltxtPrijs);

                //textbox controle
                TextBox txtprijs = new TextBox();
                txtprijs.Text = "Variabel voor input van database";
                txtprijs.ID = "txtPrijs" + i.ToString();
                txtprijs.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                txtprijs.Enabled = false;
                txtprijs.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                txtprijs.ForeColor = Color.RosyBrown;

                celltxtPrijs.Controls.Add(txtprijs);

                //cell voor Bestel button
                TableCell cellBestel = new TableCell();
                cellBestel.ID = "cellBestel" + i.ToString();
                tRow3.Controls.Add(cellBestel);

                Button btnBestel = new Button();
                btnBestel.ID = "btnBestel" + i.ToString();
                btnBestel.Text = "Kies";

                cellBestel.Controls.Add(btnBestel);

                TableCell cellAantal = new TableCell();
                cellAantal.ID = "cellAantal" + i.ToString();
                tRow3.Controls.Add(cellAantal);

                TextBox txtAantal = new TextBox();
                txtAantal.ID = "AantalGerechten" + i.ToString();
                txtAantal.Text = "Hoeveel wilt u er ?";

                cellAantal.Controls.Add(txtAantal);

                LiteralControl lt1 = new LiteralControl();
                lt1.ID = "Space " + i.ToString();
                lt1.Text = "&nbsp";

                panel.Controls.Add(lt1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = ex.Message;
        }

        return aantal;

    }
```

And this is where I make the dynamic controls. The thing is I'm stuck. All I get is one picture into the imagebuttons. And now I'm trying to make the array 2 dimensional to also add the id from each row so that the pictures don't randomly appear on the page put in the same order.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make this work ?

Comment: There is something strange about your loop in the first batch of code, why are you accessing piclist[loop, loop]? First, the second assignment deletes the previous one and second, you just seem to be feeling the cells that are positioned diagonally.

Comment: Hi Maor Veitsman, That is the problem this is kind of new for me so i was just trying something out. and what do you mean by by about the cells?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I managed to interpret your use case properly. Here is a modified version of the loop in the first batch of code you posted which should fill the data from the DataTable into a two dimensional array table with two columns.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    object[,] piclist = new object[aantal, 2]; // Note: different column number

    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Create a new DataTable

        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow drRow in dt.Rows)
        {

            // Note: accessing each column separately.
            piclist[loop, 0] = (drRow["PictureLocation"].ToString());
            piclist[loop, 1] = (drRow["MenuId"].ToString());
            loop++;

        }


    }
```

The following code updates an array of image buttons:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < piclist.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        imgBtns[x].ImageUrl = piclist[x, 0];
    }
```

Comment: Ok thank you now i get the id and the image url into an array but how do i itterate through that array to disperse them to all my image buttons?

Comment: I added some code to loop through the array that updates an image button array called imgBtns. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, you were a great help.